# Arranging $2n$ objects in specific ways

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $n$ objects $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ and another $n$ objects $b_1, b_2, ... , b_n$. We have to choose all the $2n$ objects such that $a_i$ is chosen before $a_{i+1}$ and $b_i$ is chosen before $b_{i+1}$.

Let the number of ways of choosing in such a manner is $P(n)$ for $2n$ objects. Is there a closed form of $P(n)$?

Examples:

For $n=1$, possible ways are $a_1b_1$ and $b_1a_1$

For $n=2$, possible ways are: $a_1a_2b_1b_2$, $a_1b_1a_2b_2$, $a_1b_1b_2a_2$, $b_1a_1a_2b_2$, $b_1a_1b_2a_2$, $b_1b_2a_1a_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $2n$ slots and have to choose $n$ of them for the $a$'s.  Once you do that, everything is determined, so there are ${2n \choose n}=\frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ ways to arrange them.

Comment: The most important part is all arrangements are not possible, $a_i$ comes before $a_{i+1}$ and $b_i$ comes before $b_{i+1}$. It is not being considered in your solution.
EDIT: ok got it, thanks :)

Comment: Yes it is being considered.  Once you choose the locations for the $a$'s, you have to fill them in from left to right.  The remaining locations are for the $b$'s and again you fill them from left to right.

Comment: Yeah, now I understood, thanks :)

Comment: This problem was based on https://erdos.sdslabs.co/problems/29
All the fractions in the brackets are actually $1$. So the answer is $P(1)+P(2)+...+P(60)=129183848197921031950947240904648220$. But the answer is wrong. :(